# Lilypond attaching postscript to a NoteHead

Tags: lilypond

I'm making a fingering chart for a 5-valve tuba, but having some troubles.

[image]

In the top line, I'm using lilypond's built in fingerings:

```
\relative bes,,{  <bes-0>  <b-123> ... }
```

I guess this is fine, but I'd like to make it a bit more graphical.

In the second line, I am replacing the `NoteHead` with a note-head glyph and the postscript.  I love that it is close to the `NoteHead`, but I don't like the extended ledger lines.

```
\override NoteHead.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
\override NoteHead.X-offset = 0.6
\relative bes,,{
  \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #open }
  bes
  \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #twofour }
  b
  ...
}
```

After failing to override `LedgerLineSpanner` nicely, I realized that manually re-drawing the whole `NoteHead` was probably not the right answer.  Instead, I tried to override fingering:

```
\override Fingering.parent-alignement-X = 1
\override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
\override Fingering.direction = #LEFT
\relative bes,,{
  bes\finger \markup \postscript #open
  b\finger \markup \postscript #twofour
  ...
}
```

But I'm having trouble getting it to be right of the note head.  Any suggestions?

Here is the full `*.ly`:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\header{
  tagline=##f  
}

open = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.5  2.8 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

one = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.6 0 361 arc fill
  2.5  2.8 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

onetwo = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.6 0 361 arc fill
  2.5  2.8 0.6 0 361 arc fill
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

two = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.5  2.8 0.6 0 361 arc fill  
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

twothree = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.5  2.8 0.6 0 361 arc fill  
  2.25 1.6 0.6 0 361 arc fill
  2.0  0.4 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

twofour = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.5  2.8 0.6 0 361 arc fill  
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.6 0 361 arc fill  
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

four = #"
  0.15 setlinewidth
  2.5  3.9 moveto
  2.0  3.9 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.5  2.8 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.25 1.6 0.5 0 361 arc stroke
  2.0  0.4 0.6 0 361 arc fill  
  newpath 
  0.25 2.5  moveto
  0.0  2.93 lineto
  0.43 3.18 lineto
  0.43 3.18 0.5 30 300 arcn
  closepath stroke
"

\new Staff = "main" {
  \omit Staff.TimeSignature
  \time 13/4
  \clef bass
  \set fingeringOrientations = #'(right)
  \relative bes,,{
    <bes-0>
    <b-123>
    <c-13>
    <des-23>
    <d-12>
    <ees-1>
    <e-2>
    <f-0>
    <ges-23>
    <g-12>
    <aes-1>
    <a-2>
    <bes-0>
  }\break


  \override NoteHead.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
  \override NoteHead.X-offset = 0.6

  \relative bes,,{
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #open }
    bes
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #twofour }
    b 
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #four }
    c
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #twothree }
    des
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #onetwo }
    d
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #one }
    ees
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #two }
    e
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #open }
    f
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #twothree }
    ges
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #onetwo }
    g
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #one }
    aes
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #two }
    a
    \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup{ \musicglyph "noteheads.s2" \postscript #open }
    bes
  }\break

  \revert NoteHead.stencil
  \revert NoteHead.X-offset


  \override Fingering.parent-alignment-X = 1
  \override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
  \override Fingering.direction = #RIGHT

  \relative bes,,{
    bes\finger \markup \postscript #open
    b\finger \markup \postscript #twofour
    c\finger \markup \postscript #four
    des\finger \markup \postscript #twothree
    d\finger \markup \postscript #onetwo
    ees\finger \markup \postscript #one
    e\finger \markup \postscript #two
    f\finger \markup \postscript #open
    ges\finger \markup \postscript #twothree
    g\finger \markup \postscript #onetwo
    aes\finger \markup \postscript #one
    a\finger \markup \postscript #two
    bes\finger \markup \postscript #open
  }
}

\layout{
  indent = 0\cm
  \context {
    \Score
    \omit BarNumber
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly the problem is — I don't know how to override the properties of `Fingering` to get the exact behavior you want. However, I know a simpler way of doing it (hopefully).

If you want the fingerings to be put into certain position with respect to the note (left/right/up/down), you should set `fingeringOrientations` like this:

```
\set fingeringOrientations = #'(left)
```

This will put all fingerings to the left of the notehead **if and only if** the note is a part of a chord (I have no idea why it's like this, but it's the official and well-documented behavior). So, if you write `c4-1 d4-2 e4-3` etc., setting the `fingeringOrientations` will make no difference whatsoever! But if you make these notes into one-note chords like `<c-1>4 <d-2> <e-3>`, the fingerings will go to the left.

Throwing away your Fingering overrides, and replacing the code for the third line with this:

```
\set fingeringOrientations = #'(right)

\relative bes,,{
  <bes\finger \markup \postscript \open>
  <b\finger \markup \postscript \twofour>
```

etc. will do the trick:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!  That's what I needed.  I couldn't figure out why `fingeringOrientations` wasn't working.  It was the chord behaviour.  I like this.

Comment: I also definitely would not have figured out the `\open` vs `#open` syntax on my own.

Comment: This behavior is in fact caused by the `Fingering_engraver`. This one  directly listens to fingering events, which does not work for Notes in chords (as here the articulations are not broadcasted). So the `Fingering_engraver` only handles fingerings like this `c\finger1` but not `<c\finger1>`. We also have the more advanced `New_fingering_engraver`. But as both engravers are present the `Fingering_engraver` will handle the event, at which point it gets removed from the note event. Thus the other one does not see it, so we do not get two grobs.

Comment: But this also means that the `<c\finger1>` is handled by the `New_fingering_engraver` which does use `fingeringOrientations` while `c\finger1` is handled by `Fingering_engraver`, which does not. Removing `Fingering_engraver` from the voice context will have both cases work the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Lazy, I learned something.